# Is it possible to programmatically create objects of structs and fill the fields, when you have a list of struct names and field values

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, runtime

Is it possible to programmatically create objects of structs and fill the fields, when you have a list of struct names and field values?
Say I have to read entry from (JSON)file and fill up my structs. I have value struct names and values but i want to code such that code will loop all structs and fill the in-memory data. may sound wierd, but is there a way?

Comment: You can't do it with a `struct` but you can create such a data structure using user defined types. There are a bunch of `json` libraries that do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The language feature you're looking for is called *reflection*, and C++ does not have it.

You could build up a `std::map<std::string, SomeType>` instead? If `SomeType` differs depending on the field, a `boost::variant` will allow you to store any of a number of types at any given time (it's basically a tagged union).

Or you could switch to Python. :)

Comment: is it not possible with Variadic templates? Our library usage is very limited and we are using C++11 compiler

Comment: No. Variadic templates are a compile-time construct that allow you to create class/function templates with variable numbers of template arguments.